# Missing the empathy menu after upgrade to 11.10

Tags: 11.10, unity, empathy

Since I have upgraded to 11.10 the menu in empathy is gone.

After clicking on **Chat** the **Contact List** window opens. But it has no menu. And there is no menu in the top desktop bar where the menu for chat windows appears.

Is this a bug or a new feature in empathy? But how to add new buddys then?

*Update: I have played with Compiz Config Settings and now the menu for Empathy works. Therefor I think there is a bug somewhere.*

Comment: Is it not added to the messaging applet (the mail icon next to the clock)?

Comment: There is the **Chat** item. When I click it, the **Contact List** opens. But no menu with preferences, adding new buddys, ...

Comment: I have the same problem in 12.10 using gnome-shell. I thought it was related to Unity's global menu, but I have the same issue using Ubuntu-Gnome Shell Remix. What settings did you change to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They removed that menu because the upper bar now takes place of any other application menu. Minimalize everything on your desktop except empathy. Click the empathy messenger and you can find the menu on the most upper bar on your screen. It took the menu from empathy

[image]

Comment: That is what should happen, but did not. Probably a bug. After some clicking (disabling/enabling features) in Compiz Settings the menu suddenly appeared. It is working since.